# Bash sort not sorting by time correctly

Tags: bash, sorting, logging, scripting

I am trying to sort a log to show the first 3 unique IP addresses to attack a server. I sort through the log to find failed password attempts. I then sort that output based on date. I then pipe that output to another sort based on the 11th column, to get only the first occurrence of an attack for each unique IP address. I pipe the output to the head function to get the first 3 lines then print them out using awk. The command I used is: `grep 'Failed password' auth.log | sort -k1M -nk2 -nk3 | sort -k11,11 -u | head -3 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$11}'`

The correct IP addresses are pulled from this code, but they are out of order based on time as show below:
[image]

I have tried using `-nk3.1,3.2 -nk3.4,3.5 -nk3.7,3.8` for the time instead of -nk3, but I get the same result back. **Any ideas of how to fix this issue?**

Here is a snippet of the log file for your reference:

```
Oct 11 10:12:24 myraptor sshd[29463]: Connection from 169.139.243.218 port 57273
Oct 11 10:12:25 myraptor sshd[29465]: Failed password for harvey from 169.139.243.218 port 57273 ssh2
Oct 11 10:12:25 myraptor sshd[29467]: Received disconnect from 169.139.243.218: Bye Bye
Oct 11 10:12:27 myraptor sshd[29469]: Connection from 169.139.243.218 port 57274
Oct 11 10:12:28 myraptor sshd[29471]: Failed password for harvey from 169.139.243.218 port 57274 ssh2
Oct 11 10:12:28 myraptor sshd[29473]: Failed password for harvey from 169.139.243.218 port 57274 ssh2
Oct 11 10:12:28 myraptor sshd[29475]: Received disconnect from 169.139.243.218: 11: Bye Bye
Oct 11 10:13:03 myraptor sshd[29477]: Connection from 56.13.188.38 port 55319
Oct 11 10:13:04 myraptor sshd[29479]: Failed password for harvey from 56.13.188.38 port 55319 ssh2
Oct 11 10:13:04 myraptor sshd[29481]: Received disconnect from 56.13.188.38: Bye Bye
Oct 11 10:13:15 myraptor sshd[29483]: Connection from 30.167.206.91 port 55320
Oct 11 10:13:16 myraptor sshd[29485]: Failed password for harvey from 30.167.206.91 port 55320 ssh2
Oct 11 10:13:16 myraptor sshd[29487]: Received disconnect from 30.167.206.91: Bye Bye
Oct 11 10:13:18 myraptor sshd[29489]: Connection from 30.167.206.91 port 55321
Oct 11 10:13:18 myraptor sshd[29491]: Failed password for harvey from 30.167.206.91 port 55321 ssh2
Oct 11 10:13:18 myraptor sshd[29493]: Received disconnect from 30.167.206.91: Bye Bye
```

**Expected output:**

```
Oct 11 10:12:25 169.139.243.218
Oct 11 10:13:04 56.13.188.38
Oct 11 10:13:16 30.167.206.91
```

Comment: Please, post testable sample date in text, do not post it in the comments but edit to your original question, and the related expected output.

Comment: Can you share the snippet of log file as text?

Comment: I have provided the requested information. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you please try the following:

```
grep 'Failed password' auth.log | sort -k1M -nk2 -nk3 | awk '!seen[$11]++ {print $1, $2, $3, $11}' | head -n3
```

Output:

```
Oct 11 10:12:25 169.139.243.218
Oct 11 10:13:04 56.13.188.38
Oct 11 10:13:16 30.167.206.91
```

The `awk` condition `!seen[$11]++` uniquifies the appearance of the 11th field without changing the temporal order.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt feedback! Good to know it works.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk '                    # all awk
$6=="Failed" {             # when Failed met
    if(!($11 in ips)) {    # and the ip has not been seen before
        ipc[++i]=$11       # increase stored ip counter
        ips[$11]           # and store ip for checking
        if(i==3)           # once we have 3 ips 
            exit           # we exit ie. execute END
    }
}
END {
    for(j=1;j<=i;j++)      # iterate index for ipc
        print ipc[j]       # and output
}' file
```

Output:

```
169.139.243.218
56.13.188.38
30.167.206.91
```

No use for `grep` if you are using awk anyway. And if you are using GNU awk, for most cases you can skip `sort`, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `awk` to count IP address line by line

```
 grep 'Failed password' auth.log | sort -k1M -nk2 -nk3 | sort -k11,11 | awk '!d[$11]++' | head -3 | awk '{print $1" "$2" "$3" "$11}'
```

Comment: I thought about doing that, but my concern is that if I do not have the correct order before  I do head -3, I could pull the wrong IP addresses.

Comment: Edited. Now `awk` instead of `-u` is used to remove duplicates, which won't change the order.